# Extract a larger slice than the numpy array's size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to extract a slice of length 10, beginning at index 2, of a numpy array `A`:

```
import numpy 

A = numpy.array([1,3,5,3,9])

def bigslice(A, begin_at, length):
    a = A[begin_at:begin_at + length]
    while len(a) + len(A) < length:
        a = numpy.concatenate((a,A))
    return numpy.concatenate((a, A[:length-len(a)]))

print bigslice(A, begin_at = 2, length = 10)
#[5,3,9,1,3,5,3,9,1,3]
```

This is correct. But I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this (especially when I'll have arrays of thousands of elements at the end) : I suspect the `concatenate` used here to recreate lots of new temporary arrays, and that would be un-efficient.

**How to do the same thing more efficiently ?**

Comment: You could create a generator that yields the next value in the passed array cyclically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to guarantee that you get a slice of length `length`, e.g.

```
>>> A = numpy.array([1,3,5,3,9])
>>> bigslice(A, 0, 3)
array([1, 3, 5, 3, 9, 1, 3, 5])
```

Assuming that this is an oversight, maybe you could use [`np.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html#numpy.pad), e.g.

```
def wpad(A, begin_at, length):
    to_pad = max(length + begin_at - len(A), 0)
    return np.pad(A, (0, to_pad), mode='wrap')[begin_at:begin_at+length]
```

which gives

```
>>> wpad(A, 0, 3)
array([1, 3, 5])
>>> wpad(A, 0, 10)
array([1, 3, 5, 3, 9, 1, 3, 5, 3, 9])
>>> wpad(A, 2, 10)
array([5, 3, 9, 1, 3, 5, 3, 9, 1, 3])
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer with `np.pad`. Nice, I did not know this one ! (By the way I corrected my code, so that `bigslice(A, 0, 3)` gives what I wanted. )

Answer (score 3):

Since the middle part of the array is already known to you (i.e. n repetitions of the full array), you can simply construct the middle portion using `np.tile`:

```
def cyclical_slice(A, start, length):
    arr_l = len(A)
    middle = np.tile(A, length // arr_l)

    return np.array([A[start:], middle, A[0:length - len(middle)]])
```